# how do I change the default wallpapers in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: customization, desktop-background, custom-distributions

I want to make my own OS based on Ubuntu and I want to change the default wallpaper pack (the one with all the wallpapers canonical provides) and replace it with my own custom wallpapers. I've been searching but I just cannot find the folder where the wallpapers are stored. Do you know where it is?

Comment: Are you sure? I can see [**Where are the Unity desktop wallpapers located?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/272062/179042) whilst searching. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find wallpapers from

```
 /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

Comment: Some other bits are in the Desktop Manager's folders as well - e.g. `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/noise-texture.png` is the horrible background for Gnome's login screen.