# Ubuntu Wallpapers

Tags: desktop-background

I have recently dual-booted my Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.10 , and I am really enjoying it.
I want to use all the Ubuntu wallpapers for Windows also, how can I get them?
(Where are the Ubuntu wallpapers stored? As in , which directory, so that I can just copy them and get it on Windows 7 also.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the Unity desktop wallpapers located?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272058/where-are-the-unity-desktop-wallpapers-located)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually *see* where the current background is stored, by running (in a terminal window) the command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

I get for example:

```
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Mono_Lake_by_Angela_Henderson.jpg'
```

That means my wallpaper is stored in `/usr/share/backgrounds`. In 14.10, that is the default location for wallpapers.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for the edit! (it was still early this morning :) )

Answer (score 1):

Default Ubuntu wallpapers are stored in /usr/share/backgrounds/. For each Ubuntu release, there is a new package created for the wallpapers of that release. For 14.10, the package name is ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic, you can get to see the list of wallpapers by issuing the command

```
dpkg -L ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic | grep .jpg$
```

You can also find the wallpapers for the 14.10 release in http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/all/ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic/filelist (files that end with .jpg).